# Entity Framework Core - Include Multiple Levels Not Returning All Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have a query to my EF core database which should return all the gear for each gear level for each hero.

I use the query below to get the data from the database:

```
    DbSet = context.Set<GuildMemberHero>();        

    var check = DbSet
        .Where(x => x.GuildMember.Id == guildMemberId)
        .Include(x => x.GuildMemberGearLevels).ThenInclude(y => y.GuildMemberGear)
        .Include(x => x.Hero).ThenInclude(x => x.GearLevels).ThenInclude(y => y.Gear)
        .ToList();
```

However, I am not getting all the data returned from the 'ThenInclude' statements but I am if i run a similar query in SQL itself.

Does the query to get all the items from EF remove duplicates as some of the data does have duplicate details?

Comment: You should be using `.Include(x => x.Hero).ThenInclude(h => h.GearLevels).ThenInclude(y => y.Gear)`

Comment: Camilo, I have changed the 'Include' statements to as you have suggested, and amended the question above, but am still getting the same issue

Comment: Check the executed SQL statements.

Comment: This requires a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and finally I discovered that Entity Framework uses your own implementation of Equals when mapping the data returned into classes.

Check if you have overwritten the Equals method in any of your entities and there are properties that are not being compared.